# Why can't I disable or enable the block cache?

Tags: 7

In the `admin/settings/performance` page, I (the administrator) cannot enable or disable the block cache. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As reported in that page for that setting:

> Note that block caching is inactive when modules defining content access restrictions are enabled.

If there are modules implementing `hook_node_grants()`, the "Block cache" form field is disabled.

This is the code present in [system_performance_settings()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_performance_settings/6), which is the form builder for the "Performance" form:

```
$form['block_cache']['block_cache'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios', 
  '#title' => t('Block cache'), 
  '#default_value' => variable_get('block_cache', CACHE_DISABLED), 
  '#options' => array(
    CACHE_DISABLED => t('Disabled'),
    CACHE_NORMAL => t('Enabled (recommended)'),
  ), 
  '#disabled' => count(module_implements('node_grants')), 
  '#description' => t('Note that block caching is inactive when modules defining content access restrictions are enabled.'),
);
```

As alternative, there could be a module that is disabling the form field to avoid the option can be selected; I don't know of any module that does that, even if I cannot exclude there is a module that is effectively doing it.

Answer (score 6):

I know you asked *"why?"* not *"can i get around that problem"*... but you can get around that problem without removing modules that use `hook_node_grants()`. Try out the [Block Cache Alter module](http://drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter). It allows, among other things, the ability to use block caching even if modules implement `hook_node_grants()`.

Comment: Instead of using that module, adding `$conf['block_cache_bypass_node_grants'] = TRUE;` to settings.php should be investigated first if you know what you're doing with your blocks.